# Illegal reflective access

Tags: spring, command-line, spring-batch

JDK11 + Spring batch `CommandLineJobRunner`

Does anyone know what those warnings mean:

> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
>   WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (jar:file:/Users/boru/Downloads/spcljr/build/libs/spcljr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
>   WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
>   WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
>   WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Comment: try upgrade JDK 11 to the newer version and see.

Comment: Which jdk distribution/version do you use? I tried openJdk 11.0.2 with SB 4.2.0 and I don't see this warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this one reported already.You can keep your eyes on this ticket

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22814

If you can't wait, you try different versions and see

Comment: Thanks Nghia, it helps me

Comment: Mark it if you think it is useful

Answer (score 0):

```
I used this pom and my problem disappeared:
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.universidad.springboot.backend.academia</groupId>
    <artifactId>academia</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>academia</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2
        <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId> <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version> </dependency> <https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-jwt
        <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9.RELEASE</version> </dependency> -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>1.4.194</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-jwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.walterjwhite.java.dependencies/hikari-jdbc-connection-pool -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.walterjwhite.java.dependencies</groupId>
            <artifactId>hikari-jdbc-connection-pool</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.17</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```